# Fluently choosing which component to inject

Tags: castle-windsor

I have some components implementing the same interface and I would like to chose which one gets injected to my `Repository`.

```
 Component.For<IRepository>().ImplementedBy<Repository>().<whatShouldGoHere>()
```

I thought I had this working with `DependsOn` but now I saw that `DependsOn` are for static dependecies such as strings. Is the `IHandlerSelector` the only way forward? I would rather have the declaration inline with the component registration. Maybe a factory method? Are there any recommendations?

Edit
Example Constructor

```
public PersitentRepository(Func<ISession,string> sessionFactory)
```

Digging around I realize that the delegate is an artifact from the `TypedFactoryFacility`. There seems to have been some change so it now resolves by type only. In older Castle versions the string argument was used to select component by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DependsOn does work for other things than statics, the problem is that the injected delegate does not resolve the way it used to. I ended up registering my own component for handling this specific delegate

```
container.Register(Component.for<Func<ISession,string>>().ImplementedBy(sessionName => container.resolve<ISession>(sessionName));
```

(I typed the above from memory so please excuse any typos)

Answer (score 2):

A factory would to the trick.

You need to add the `FactorySupportFacility` to your container for this to work.

For much more detail, see the Castle Windsor documentation at http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Factory-Support-Facility&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1.

See also http://www.mail-archive.com/castle-project-users@googlegroups.com/msg04463.html.

Comment: The Component I am trying to create is of the generic variety so I rather avoid factories. Thanks for the suggestion though.